# How to support Cyrillic alphabet in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, utf

How to make it so that when the Russian language is output, Russian letters are output, and not �� ����� �������� �����! It does not work only in the console, but everything is ok in the terminal

I've tried this

1. Window > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types.
2. Window > Preferences > General > Workspace, set Text file encoding to Other : UTF-8

and this

Window -> Preferences -> Expand General and click Workspace, text file encoding (near bottom) has an encoding chooser.
Select "Other" radio button -> Select UTF-8 from the drop down

and this

Open eclipse.ini in your eclipse home directory Or STS.ini in case of STS(Spring Tool Suite)
put the line below at the end of the file
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

but it still can't be done.
help pls!

Comment: The problem is your font. "General > Appearance > Color and Fonts > Terminal > Terminal Console Font". Select a font that supports your desired glyphs. Good luck!

Comment: *set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types.* I never quite get that kind of advice - surely it would only work for *subsequent* source files? If the current encoding of your source files is *not* Unicode (quite likely in WIndows) then it's not likely to suddenly make your source come good is it?

Comment: Java strings are always Unicode regardless of the source file encoding so they always support Cyrillic. As already stated it looks like the font your console is using does not support the Cyrillic characters.

Comment: *It does not work only in the console, but everything is ok in the terminal* The way I interpret that is that the "terminal" is cmd.exe and the "console" is the Eclipse input/output area. Please say if that's not correct

Answer (score 1):

That the glyph "�" is displayed is an indication that the issue is not the encoding (the mapping of the binary code to a character or vice-versa), but the mapping of a character to the related graphical representation (usually referred to as 'glyph').

The latter comes with the font files, but not all font files do provide glyphs for all characters, and missing characters will then be shown as the replacement or default glyph, defined by that font file.

Quite often is this the diamond with the question mark, but other pictures are known as well (so the open rectangle or a rectangle with a question mark).

To display the Cyrillic text, you need to select a font that covers the respective Unicode section – best would be a font covering the whole Unicode range.

Comment: No single font provides glyphs for the entire range of over 144,000 Unicode characters. I suggest you delete that last clause.

Comment: @BasilBourque – Not yet perhaps, but its on its way: http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html. And that there is no font covering the whole Unicode range nowadyas does not mean that it would be still the best to use one … it's just not possible yet.